# How do I show that formal logarithm is the inverse of the formal exponential?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, formal-power-series

Let $A$ be a unital commutative and associative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

Define $exp(f):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n}{n!}$ for each $f\in XA[[X]]$.

Define $log(f):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (f-1)^n$ for each $f\in 1+XA[[X]]$.

Hence, we have two maps $exp:XA[[X]]\rightarrow 1+XA[[X]]$ and $log:1+XA[[X]]\rightarrow XA[[X]]$.

I am trying to prove that $log$ map is the inverse of the $exp$ map.

The first thing I tried is to directly show $log\circ exp=id$ and $exp\circ log = id$ by checking if the identities hold for every element $f$, but this does not work well since this way involves too many calculations. For example, $$[X^n]exp(log(f))=[X^n]\sum_{k=0}^n log(f)^k/k! = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} [X^n]log(f)^k= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} [X^n](\sum_{l=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{l+1}}{l} (f-1)^l)^k$$.

Thus, we have to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} [X^n](\sum_{l=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{l+1}}{l} (f-1)^l)^k=[X^n]f$$.

But this calculation is really a nightmare.. Is there a clever way to show this? If not, how do I wisely calculate to show the above identity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This actually follows from the corresponding fact about actual functions over the reals. The point being that if $\log \circ \exp$ and $\exp \circ \log$ are equal to the identity as functions over the reals then the corresponding Taylor series must also be equal, and that implies the corresponding identity of formal power series. Said another way, analytic functions embed into formal power series, in a way compatible with addition, multiplication, and composition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How do we embed $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Say $A=\mathbb{Q}[X_1,X_2,...]$. And the above formal log definition is not well-defined over reals.. could you give me some more details?

Comment: It's unnecessary to embed $A$ anywhere. The desired identities are true universally in the sense that exp and log are inverses as formal power series over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Similarly, in order to prove that $\frac{1}{1 - f} = 1 + f + f^2 + \dots$ for all $f \in x A[[x]]$ I actually only have to prove it for a single $f$, namely $f = x \in x \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, whereupon it's true universally.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Composition_of_series , composition of formal power series is only defined if the inner power series has no constant term. Does that mean that this argument works for $\exp \circ \log$ but not $\log \circ \exp$?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible argument. One way to define the exponential $\exp(x)$ as a formal power series is that it is the unique formal power series $f(x)$ (over any commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra) satisfying $f(0) = 1$ and

$$f'(x) = f(x).$$

Repeatedly differentiating this identity easily gives $[x^n] \exp(x) = \frac{1}{n!}$ as expected. Similarly, one way to define the logarithm $\log (1 + x)$ as a formal power series is that it is the unique formal power series $g(x)$ satisfying $g(0) = 0$ and

$$g'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n.$$

So what can we say about the composite $\exp \log (1 + x)$? Well, by the formal chain rule, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x) = f(g(x)) \frac{1}{1 + x}.$$

So $f(g(x))$ is a solution $h(x)$ to the differential equation $h'(x) = h(x) \frac{1}{1 + x}$ with initial condition $h(0) = f(g(0)) = 1$. We clearly have $h(x) = 1 + x$ is a solution, and we can appeal to a formal version of the Picard-Lindelof theorem to assert that formal solutions to ODEs exist and are unique, so we conclude that

$$\exp \log (1 + x) = 1 + x.$$

Similarly, what can we say about $\log \exp x = \log ((\exp x - 1) + 1)$? Well, again by the formal chain rule, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(f(x) - 1) = g'(f(x) - 1) f'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = 1.$$

So $g(f(x) - 1)$ is a solution to the ODE $\frac{d}{dx} h(x) = 1$ with initial condition $h(0) = g(f(0) - 1) = 0$. Here it's a bit simpler to see that we must have $h(x) = x$, so

$$\log \exp(x) = x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be
(feeling too lazy right now
to work out
all the details)
to use the functional equations:

For ln,
$f(xy) = f(x)+f(y),
f'(1) = 1$.

For exp,
$g(x+y) = g(x)g(y),
g'(0) = 1$.

From these,
can get
$f'(x)
=\dfrac1{x}
$
and
$g'(x) = g(x)$.