# can we define logarithm function $\log$ on $\mathbb C((T))$

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponential-function

Let $\mathbb C[[T]]$ be the ring of formal power series in one formal variable $T$, and $\mathbb C((T))$ be its fraction field. At first we can definitely define the exponential function $\exp:\mathbb C((T))\to \mathbb C((T))$ by 
$$
f\mapsto \exp(f):= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^k}{k!}
$$
However it seems there are troubles in defining $\log$. For example, for any $a$ we can naively 'put' $\log(f)=\log(a)+\log(1+\frac{f-a}{a})$ and in a similar way we may use the Taylor expansion to the last term.

> Note that a meaningful definition of $\log$ should satisfy $\log \circ
>  \exp =id$ or $\exp \circ \log=id$.

So, it seems that the definition depends on $a$, right or not? Let me put the question simpler: is it possible to define $\log(T)$ in $\mathbb C((T))$?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486706/how-do-i-show-that-formal-logarithm-is-the-inverse-of-the-formal-exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

> At first we can definitely define the exponential function...

In fact, you can't define the formal exponential *even* in $\Bbb C[[T]]$. If $f(T) = a_0 + a_1T + \cdots$ with $a_0\ne 0$, the 0-th term of $\exp(f)$ is the *infinite* sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_0^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: But we are working with $\mathbb C$, and this is just $e^{a_0}\in \mathbb C$, right?

Comment: @Hang, *formal* series means *always finite sums*.